# Lambda join on string list C#

Tags: c#, linq, lambda

I was trying to get common emails from two list. But my query never returns any value.

```
List<string> list1=new List<string>();
list1.Add("abc@gmail.com");
list1.Add("abc@hotmail.com");

List<string> list2=new List<string>();
list2.Add("abc@gmail.com");

var tempList = list1.Join(list2, x => x, y=> y, (x,y) => x).Select(x => x);
```

But when I change my list to a object type its start returning result.

```
List<Email> list1=new List<Email>();
list1.Add(new Email {Address = "abc@gmail.com"});
list1.Add(new Email {Address = "abc@hotmail.com"});

List<Email> list2=new List<Email>();
list2.Add(new Email {Address = "abc@hotmail.com"});
var tempList = list1.Join(list2, x => x.Address, y=> y.Address, (x,y) => x).Select(x => x);
```

Now this query is returning the result.
What I'm doing wrong here? Or there is some other behavior which is I'm not aware of. Following linq expression is also working fine.

```
 var result2 = from item1 in list1
               join item2 in list2
               on item1 equals item2
               select new { item1 };
```

Comment: `.Select(x => x)` actually does nothing.

Comment: @YeldarKurmangaliyev yes, you are right. it does nothing. But why the join is not returning anything?

Comment: The code above works fine. All versions of it, including the one you say doesn't. Without a good [mcve] that reliably reproduces the problem you are having, it's impossible to provide a useful, correct answer.

Comment: list1.AddRange(list2.ToArray());

Comment: @PeterDuniho I was doing wrong in code but when I wrote code here mistakenly I wrote it into correct format. Thanks for correction :)

Comment: Would I be correct in saying that the code that didn't work is actually `List<Email> list1 = ...; List<Email> list2 = ...; var tempList = list1.Join(list2, x => x, y => y, (x, y) => x).Select(x => x);`?

Comment: @Enigmativity yes, you are right. But above code is also correct :) Please read comments.

Comment: @Haris - How can I be right (that I posted the code that **doesn't** work) and the yet the code **works correctly** too?

Comment: So, do you actually have a problem you need help with? If not, please just delete this question, as it is doing no one any good and is wasting the time of people who are looking for other people who actually _do_ need some help.

Comment: @PeterDuniho I'm trying to delete the question. But this question has been answered. So I'm unable to delete it.

Answer (score 1):

As I see your code works correct, may be you just forgot call ToList() for viewing the result.

[image]

Comment: it also works without using .ToList(). I was doing wrong in code but when I wrote code here mistakenly I wrote it into correct format. But thanks for your quick answer.

Answer (score -1):

Just use intersect instead

```
var tempList = list1.Intersect(list2);
```

I wasn't able to replicate your initial issue. It was giving me the exact same response as this solution does.

Comment: It actually does not answer the **"why does that work, and this doesn't"** question.

Comment: @FloatingKiwi .Intersect() also works. But I want to do it by using the lambda expression. The problem is resolved. I was doing wrong in code but when I wrote code here mistakenly I wrote it into correct format.